# how to get only keys from firebase and put it inside recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

i have this data structure to create bus schedules and provide the timings. i am not sure on how can i get the keys to get the timing

```
  "Schedules" : {
"Apu-to-vista" : {
  "11:00" : "true",
  "12:00" : "true",
  "13:00" : "true",
  "13:30" : "true",
  "14:00" : "true",
  "14:30" : "true",
  "15:00" : "true",
  "15:30" : "true",
  "16:00" : "true",
  "16:30" : "true",
  "17:00" : "true",
  "17:30" : "true",
  "18:00" : "true",
  "18:30" : "true",
  "19:00" : "true",
  "20:30" : "true"
},
"vista-to-apu" : {
  "11:35" : "true",
  "12:00" : "true",
  "13:00" : "true",
  "13:15" : "true",
  "14:00" : "true",
  "14:30" : "true",
  "15:00" : "true",
  "15:30" : "true",
  "16:00" : "true",
  "16:30" : "true",
  "17:00" : "true",
  "17:30" : "true",
  "18:00" : "true",
  "18:30" : "true",
  "19:20" : "true",
  "20:30" : "true"
}
}
```

I want to get the keys if i do `mDatabase.getReference("Schedules").child("Apu-to-vista")`

this is what i tried so far

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vista, container, false);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    fromAPU = mDatabase.getReference("Schedules").child("Apu-to-vista");
    toAPU = mDatabase.getReference("Schedules").child("Vista-to-apu");
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fromAPURecycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Schedule, ViewHolder>(
            Schedule.class, R.layout.card_view, ViewHolder.class, toAPU.orderByKey()
    ){
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Schedule model, int position) {
            viewHolder.mTime.setText(getRef(position).getKey());
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final TextView mTime;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_holder);

    }
}
```

ive tried using firebase recycler adapter create the class consist of only String timeText, and putting it into recyclerview. however there is an error
the error said no adapter attached: skipping layout

i am just beginner in android, can someone help me. thank you

Comment: What does `getRef(position).getKey()` return?

Comment: i tried to logged it but it doesnt give me anything, since the error catched no adapter attached

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the keys from **Apu-to-vista**:

```
fromAPU.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot apuToVistaSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot scheduleSnapshot : apuToVistaSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String key  = scheduleSnapshot.getKey();
                    // Do whatever you want with this key
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Firebase sends you the data wrapped in a `DataSnapshot`object. After the call of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` on the `fromAPU` reference Firebase will send you the `apuToVistaSnapshot` which includes all the data of the "Apu-to-vista" node.

By calling `getChildren()` on that reference you can iterate through its child `DataSnapshot`instances and get the key from each one.

Comment: yes, i tried to logged it and it works, however my next problem is how to put it into my adapter on recycler view

Comment: If you've tried and it works as you said, you should upvote to mark this answer as useful if not correct (where you should mark it as correct). This is how this community works.